# Al reiniciar UBUNTU SERVER 18 se pierde configuracion de red

Tags: ubuntu, servidor, redes

les comento recientemente uno de mis servidores con UBUNTU SERVER 18 me ha presentado una falla a nivel de la tarjeta madre un condensador y como solución mas practica he sacado el disco duro y lo he colocado en otra computadora, al iniciar el sistema todo pareciera andar sin problemas pero no se activa mi configuración de red.
Al hacer ifconfig solo me da resultados de la red lo

```
$ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Bucle local
          Direc. inet:127.0.0.1  Másc:255.0.0.0
          Dirección inet6: ::1/128 Alcance:Anfitrión
          ACTIVO BUCLE FUNCIONANDO  MTU:65536  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:0 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:0 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:0
          Bytes RX:0 (0 KB)  TX bytes:0 (0 KB)
```

Al hacer ip addr sucede esto

```
 $ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: enp0s18: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:13:8f:8f:e8:97 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 186.92.108.80/19 brd 186.92.127.255 scope global enp0s18
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::213:8fff:fe8f:e897/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

De manera temporal he solicionado  haciendo esto:

```
$ sudo ifconfig enp0s18 up
$ sudo dhclient enp0s18
```

Y funciona de manera temporal porque al reiniciar el servidor todo queda como estaba antes, es decir tengo que repetir el paso que describi anteriormente, ya hice update y upgrade motivado a que estoy en otra pc no en donde se instalo el sistema. Me gustaría saber como puedo hacer que la configuración quede como esta sin necesidad de que yo tenga que activar la red de manera manual.

Answer (score 0):

Cambiar disco duro de un pc a otro, con su respectivo S.O. ocasiona inestabilidad, a menos que los dos pc sean exactamente iguales en hardware. El kernel trae módulos genéricos, sea para las tarjetas de red u otro hardware, estos módulos sirven de manera rudimentaria y tosca en ese hardware en especial, pero para su mejor funcionamiento, uno se ve obligado activa en el kernel o instalar de una fuente externa el modulo especifico para ese harware.

Una ventaja de Ubuntu y ya de casi todas las distros, es que en el proceso de instalación, detectan tu hardware y te activan una configuración especial para ella, cosa que no pasa en Gentoo del cual soy usuario, que te toca a mano en el proceso de instalación compilar los modulos del kernel para tu hardware.

Ademas también puede ser que te sucede eso porque dejaste loco a [udev](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev_(Espa%C3%B1ol)); este se encarga de detectar tu hardware y montar los respectivos módulos de este.

Supongo que el problema es ese, cuestión de modulos o como en windows los llaman, drivers, consulta la referencia de tu tarjeta y averigua que módulos necesita, en ubuntu por lo general es solo instalar un paquete y problema resuelto.

Ahora, a menos que sean hardwares exactamente iguales, en todo, desde board, tipo y generación de procesador, tarjeta de red, etc, no recomiendo hacer se cambio de disco duro con S.O. incluido, ya que este está configurado e instalado para otro hardware.

---

A ciencia cierta, saber cual es tu problema, es complicado, ya que solo la información que das es solo la de `ip addr` y `ifconfig`, aunque me huelo que el problema va por donde te indique.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta desactivando

```
ifdown enp0s18
```

Edita el archivo **/etc/network/interfaces** asignandole la IP que le dabas con dhclient. Ahí debería guardar todos los cambios y haces [ifconfig](https://linux.lat/como-usar-el-comando-ifconfig/) enp0s18 up